# Putting Query Results Inside Array to PHP Email Attachments

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, email-attachments

I seriously don't know how to do this.
The user is allowed to attached as many recipe.pdf they want.. but i don't know how to put it inside array. Can you guys show me how?

Here's my code.

```
include('connect.php');
$db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_database);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recipe_list");
echo "<ul>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
foreach($row as $recipe)
echo "<li>"<input type='checkbox[]' value='".$recipe."' checked /><label>".$recipe."</label></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Next Code is the Part where I have the Email Attachments..
I seriously don't know how to do the array part.

```
$file_folder = "/home/rdash/public_html/recipes/";
$recipes = array("recipe_001.pdf","recipe_002.pdf");
$files = array ($file_folder.$recipes[0], $file_folder.$recipes[1]);
```

In this code, i already input pdf names.
But how am i going to **pull the $recipe from the first code?**
I'm talking about the recipes from the query results. The one with the checkboxes.
Please help me.
**If you'll need more details. Just ask :) Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
include('connect.php');
$db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_database);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recipe_list");
echo "<ul>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){ // assume your filed name is recipe
    echo "<li><input type='checkbox' name='recipes[]' value='".$row['recipe']."' checked /><label>".$row['recipe']."</label></li>";
}
```

on next page you will get as `$_POST`, if you set your form to post, an array (`$_POST['recipes']`) with recipe names.

EDIT: if you just need the array:

```
$recipes = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){ // assume your filed name is recipe
    $recipes[] = $row['recipe'];
}
// do whatever you want with $recipes array
```

Comment: i'm so sorry, i don't understand your answer :(. can you please explain what you mean.. how am i gonna do it with codes? Please..

Comment: That is not a form, it just display the query results. Would it be easier if it was inside a form?

Comment: I really don't know what you mean. I don't know what to do... stuck here forever?

Comment: CAN SOMEONE JUST PLEASE... HELP ME.

Comment: edited .. if you just need the array

Comment: aaw. you were too late. I already figured it out.. BUT THANKS! appreciated everything :) i used this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554961/how-do-i-add-data-from-a-php-form-into-an-array/554970#554970